(ConTeXt) Github ConTeXT Garden presentation example github link is extremely confusing, can I get help on how to understand it or another template?
So what I tried doing as a complete novice to ConTeXt was try to figure out how to make document, i come from LaTeX where I am also a novice and I was able to make an AI generated (not entirely but it got me started) template that I have here
https://github.com/adityam/context-slides-example
What I am trying to do is get slides and presentations done in ConTeXT. However the github linked in a section of the garden wiki is not working for me, what I did was try to put all the slides.tex code first and then the examples.tex code second, but this didn't work. I would love it if I could have the 12pt TImes New roman style and american setting for my LMTX version slides.
ConTeXt version: 2024.07.31 19:43

What's your goal here, and what isn't working with your attached sample? For slides with Times New Roman, a very basic example would be \setupbodyfont[times, 36pt] \setuppapersize[SW] \starttext Hello, world! \stoptext, although you'll probably want to style it a little more for a real document.

You can look through $TEXMFDIST/doc/context/presentations/ for some more detailed examples of ConTeXt presentations, although lots of them use some pretty advanced techniques. Specifically, the file context/2021/context-2021-programming.tex is a pretty good example of a simple-ish presentation made in ConTeXt.

@MaxChernoff Hey man, thanks for responding with all this, I ran the context/2021/context-2021-programming.tex code and edited it to have the SW Size but the... border thing is sort of tricky to remove. I preferred using your very short code and editing it to utilize 12pt andtimes, it just looked more attractive
My goal here is to get the margins to be smaller, I don't know the dimensions of SW in inches and it doesnt seem to say anything on Context garden but I would love to edit this to have even margins, I also recall trying to set .5in margins in a regular doc but I had trouble

@MaxChernoff perhaps you could help me with that issue? (well, technically two but maybe you can do a two in one, also I disabled the page number for the slides with \setuppagenumbering[state=stop]

This is meant as a tutorial. You should read the git comments to understand or see this webpage which shows the output: https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/presentation-40-commits-redux/

I regenerated all the PDFs on the page with the latest ConTeXt and everything appears to be working correctly. If there is something specific that doesn't work, please let me know.


can I get help on how to understand it or another template?


What I am trying to do is get slides and presentations done in ConTeXt.

To answer your question more generally, here's a simplified version of my personal ConTeXt presentation style:
%% Basic Setup
\mainlanguage[en]
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\let\slide=\page

%% Fonts
\usebodyfont[plex, plex-light]
\setupbodyfont[plex, sans, 24pt]

%% Colours
\definecolor[light]      [x=F3F3F3]
\definecolor[light-faded][x=666666]
\definecolor[dark]       [x=202729]
\definecolor[dark-faded] [x=434748]

\setupcolors[textcolor=light]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=dark]
\setupinteraction[color=, contrastcolor=,]

%% Sectioning
\define\sectionrule{%
    \vskip -0.75em
    \dontleavehmode\centerline{\blackrule[
        width=0.6\textwidth,
        color=light-faded,
        height=2pt,
    ]}%
    \vskip 0.25ex
}

\startsetups[style:chapter]
    \startstandardmakeup[align=middle]
        \headtextcontent
        \vskip -0.5ex
        \sectionrule
    \stopstandardmakeup
\stopsetups

\defineheadalternative[my:chapter][renderingsetup=style:chapter]

\setuphead[chapter][
    alternative=my:chapter,
    page=yes,
    header=empty,
    style=\rmbfc
]

\define[2]\protectedgobbletwo{}

\setuphead[section][ % Ugly Hack!
    command=\protectedgobbletwo,
    alternative=margintext,
    page=yes,
]

\setupheader[text][
    style={\rmbic\veryraggedcenter},
    after=\sectionrule,
]

\setupheadertexts[section]

%% Title Page
\startsetups[document:start]
    \setupinteraction[
        title=\documentvariable{title},
        author=\documentvariable{author},
    ]

    \startstandardmakeup[align=middle, pagestate=start]
        {\rmbfc \documentvariable{title}}
        \sectionrule
        {\ss \documentvariable{author}}
    \stopstandardmakeup
\stopsetups

%% Page Layout
\setuppapersize[SW]
\setupinterlinespace[2.75ex]
\setupwhitespace[big]

\setuplayout[
    topspace=0.05\paperheight,
    backspace=0.1\paperwidth,
    width=middle,
    height=middle,
    header=0.15\paperheight,
    footer=0.05\paperheight,
]

\setupfootertexts[margin][][{
    \hskip -2.25em \color[light-faded]{%
        \switchtobodyfont[plex-light, sans, 14pt]
        \documentvariable{info}
    }
}]

%% Page Numbering
\startuseMPgraphic{pagenumber}
    numeric bar_height;  bar_height := 0.025 * PaperHeight;
    numeric total_width; total_width := 0.9 * TextWidth;
    numeric bar_width;   bar_width := total_width / \totalnumberofpages;

    fill unitsquare
        xyscaled (total_width, bar_height)
        withcolor \MPcolor{dark-faded}
    ;

    fill unitsquare
        xyscaled (bar_width, bar_height)
        shifted  ((\realfolio - 1) * bar_width, 0)
        withcolor \MPcolor{light-faded}
    ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\setupfooter[style=small]
\setupfootertexts[\useMPgraphic{pagenumber}]

% Steps
\define\startsteps{\grabbufferdata[steps][startsteps][stopsteps]}
\let\nextstep=\relax

\startluacode
    interfaces.implement{
        name    = "stopsteps",
        public  = true,
        actions = function ()
            local buffer = buffers.getcontent("steps")

            local split = {}
            for text in buffer:gsub("\\nextstep", "#"):gmatch"([^#]+)" do
                table.insert(split, text)
            end

            for i, text in ipairs(split) do
                context(table.concat({table.unpack(split, 1, i)}, "\n"))
                context.page()
            end
        end
    }
\stopluacode

%% Tiling, only for this example document
% \definepapersize[demo][
%     width=\dimexpr 3\paperwidth + 10pt,
%     height=\dimexpr 4\paperheight + 10pt,
% ]
% \setuppapersize[SW][demo]
% \setuppaper[nx=3, ny=4]
% \setuparranging[XY]

%% Demonstration
\startdocument[
    title={Example Presentation},
    author={Example Author},
    info={Example Info},
]
    \chapter{Example Chapter}

    \section{Example Section}

    \startsteps
        First step

        \nextstep

        Second step

        \nextstep

        Third step
    \stopsteps

    \slide

    Same section, but a different slide.

    \section{Another Section}

    \startsteps
        \externalfigure[sys:///cow.pdf][
            height=0.45\textheight,
            background=color,
            backgroundcolor=white,
        ]

        \nextstep

        \vfill \externalfigure[sys:///cow.pdf][
            height=0.45\textheight,
            width=\textwidth,
            background=color,
            backgroundcolor=white,
        ]
    \stopsteps

    \chapter{Another Chapter}

    \section{Example Section}

    Slide one.

    Still slide one.

    Also still slide one.

    \slide

    Slide two.

    Still slide two.

    Also still slide two.

    \section{The End}

    The end.
\stopdocument


For a longer sample, you can look at my TUG 2022 presentation which is styled pretty similar to what I posted above.


I would love it if I could have the 12pt TImes New roman style and american setting for my LMTX version slides.


I preferred using your very short code and editing it to utilize 12pt andtimes, it just looked more attractive My goal here is to get the margins to be smaller, I don't know the dimensions of SW in inches and it doesnt seem to say anything on Context garden but I would love to edit this to have even margins, I also recall trying to set .5in margins in a regular doc but I had trouble

Setting the font to Times is quite easy with ConTeXt. It's also fairly easy to change the font and margin sizes, but for presentation slides, it doesn't really make sense to use absolute sizes like 0.5in and 12pt since unlike a sheet of letter/A4 paper, the slides will be whatever size your projection screen is.
Below is a more basic example that should meet your specified criteria. I also added a background image and changed the colour of the text, but you can remove that if you want.
%% Layout
\setuppapersize[SW]
\setuplayout[
    backspace=0.1\paperheight, % Left/right margins are 10% of the paper height
    topspace=0.1\paperheight, % Top/bottom margins are 10% of the paper height
    header=0pt, % No headers or footers
    footer=0pt,
    width=middle, % Center the page vertically and horizontally
    height=middle,
]

%% Fonts
\setupbodyfont[times, 24pt]
\setupcolors[textcolor=darkred]

%% Background
\definetransparency[background][a=normal, t=0.15]
\defineoverlay[background][{%
    \starttransparent[background]%
        \externalfigure[sys:///cow.pdf][
            height=\overlayheight,
            width=\overlaywidth,
            background=color,
            backgroundcolor=lightgreen,
        ]%
    \stoptransparent%
}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=background]

%% Sections
\setuphead[chapter, section, subsection][page=yes, number=no]

%% Tiling, only for this example document
% \definepapersize[demo][
%     width=\dimexpr 2\paperwidth + 10pt,
%     height=\dimexpr 2\paperheight + 10pt,
% ]
% \setuppapersize[SW][demo]
% \setuppaper[nx=2, ny=2]
% \setuparranging[XY]

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Section 1}
    First slide

    \section{Section 2}
    \samplefile{ward}

    \page

    \externalfigure[sys:///hacker.jpg][height=\textheight, width=\textwidth]

    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \startitemize
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Third item
    \stopitemize
\stoptext


